# MPI Fundamentals

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I have a basic question regarding MPI, to get a better understanding of it (I am new to MPI and multiple processes so please bear with me on this one). I am using a simulation environment in C++ (RepastHPC) that makes extensive use of MPI (using the Boost libraries) to allow parallel operations. In particular, the simulation consists of multiple instances of the respective classes (i.e. agents), that are supposed to interact with each other, exchange information etc. Now given that this takes place on multiple processes (and given my rudimentary understanding of MPI) the natural question or fear I have is, that agents on different processes don't intereact with each other anymore because they cannot connect (I know, this contradicts the entire idea of MPI).

After reading the manual my understanding is this: the available libraries of Boost.MPI (and also the libaries of the above mentionend package) take care of all of the  communication and sending packages back and forth between processes, i.e. each process has copies of the instances from other processes (I guess this is some form of call by value, b/c the original instance cannot be changed from a process that has only a copy), then an updating takes place, to ensure that the copies of the instances have the same information as the originals and so on.

Does this mean, that in terms of the final outcomes of the simulations runs, I get the same as if I would be doing the entire thing on one process? Put differently, the multiple processes are just supposed to speed up things but not change the design of simulation (thus I don't have to worry about it)?

Comment: It would be a design aim for anyone producing software for parallel execution that it should produce correct results when run on multiple processes.  What tests have you run to understand whether or not the software you refer to achieves this aim ?  Of course using the results from a serial execution to validate results from parallel execution depends on assurance that serial execution is itself producing correct results.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I misphrased my problem in the beginning, I am not using the software currently, more so considering using it, so I have not run any tests to this point, but this is definitely a good starting point. I have no doubt that the designers of the software did their job properly, my question was rather concerned with whether the general purpose of the software is to achieve the same result from parallel execution as from serial execution (i.e. if I implement it correctly).

Comment: Regarding testing, this is one way I could think of, to make sure it works properly (let me know if there is a simpler way): 1. Create two Agents (ID 1, ID 2) endowed with two apples each, create two Agents (ID 3, ID 4)endowed with two oranges each. 2. Let each Agent go through the list of Agents and whenever someone has a different fruit than they do, give it to them.

Comment: Running this once (or on every odd number of runs), I should end up with Agents 1 and 2 having two oranges each and 3 and 4 having two apples, if communication between the processes works correctly, right?

Comment: Also, is there a simple way to set the number of parallel processes to 1 when linking the program (pratically to turn off the MPI part)? In order to see compare the results between parallel and serial execution. I tried simple versions now, compiling with 'mpicxx main.cpp', and running with 'mpirun -n 2 ./main', however I cannot seem to set the number to one, because the linking does not seem to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of MPI here. MPI is not an automatic parallelization library. It isn't a distributed shared memory mechanism. It doesn't do any magic for you.

What it does do is make it simpler to communicate between different processes on the same or different machines. Each process has its own address space which does not overlap with the other processes (unless you're doing something else outside of MPI). Assuming you set up your MPI installation correctly, it will do all of the pain of setting up the communication channels between your processes for you. It also gives you some higher level abstractions like collective communication.

When you use MPI, you compile your code differently than normal. Instead of using `g++ -o code code.cpp` (or whatever your compiler is), you use `mpicxx -o code code.cpp`. This will automatically link with all of the MPI stuff necessary. Then when you run your application, you use `mpiexec -n <num_processes> ./code` (other arguments aren't required, but are probably necessary) . The argument `num_processes` will tell MPI how many processes to launch. This isn't done at compile/link time.

You will also have to rewrite your code to use MPI. MPI has lots of functions (the standard is available [here](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) and there are lots of tutorials available on the web that are easier to understand) that you can use. The basics are `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`, but there's lots and lots more. You'll have to find a tutorial for that.

Comment: Thank you for clarifiying. I did indeed have a misunderstanding of MPI. The software package that I am using was describing in detail in its manual how it sets up the exchange of data in between processes and I see why now, because this not done automatically by MPI, as you pointed out, but rather the layout for communication is provided for that purpose. Thanks also for the pdf, I was looking for a documentation like that.

Comment: I would recommend looking at LLNL's tutorial.  It's available at https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/.  They also have other tutorials for pthreads and other common parallelization libraries and language primitives.